# change javascript function to work with list instead of string

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function string_to_url(string) {
    var replace = new Array('\u00E1','\u00C1','\u00E9','\u00C9','\u00ED','\u00CD','\u00F3','\u00D3','\u00FA','\u00DA','\u00FC','\u00DC','\u00F6','\u00D6','\u00F5','\u00D5','\u00FB','\u00DB','\u00BE','\u0161','\u00E8','\u017E','\u00FD','\u00F4','\u00E4','\u00F2','\u00E5','\u00BC','\u0160','\u00C8','\u017D','\u00DD','\u00D2','\u00C5','\u00EC','\u00CC','\u00EA','\u00C6','\u00E6','\u00D8','\u00F8');
    var replace_n = new Array('a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O', 'u','U','u','U','o','O','o','O','u','U','l','s','c','z','y','o','a','n','a','l','s','C','Z','Y','N','A','e','E','e','AE', 'ae','O','o');

    for (var i = 0; i < replace.length; i++) {
        string = string.replace(replace[i], replace_n[i]);
    }

    return string;
}
```

And I want to change it to work with list of list instead of string.

For example `[["\u00C1\u00ED",4],[["\u00ED\u00CD",2],["\u00CD\u00C1",1]]`

Any idea? I am new on javascript and I cannot continue with the script

Comment: First suggestion, don't use the `new Array` construct.  You should be using array literals (use the `[ ... ]` syntax).  Also, they should be defined outside of the function itself since they are essentially constants and don't need to be re-initialized on every function call.

Comment: You need to write a nested loop. Are you new to Javascript, or new to programming in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = [["\u00C1\u00ED",4],[["\u00ED\u00CD",2],["\u00CD\u00C1",1]];

for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
    string_to_url(list[i]);
}
```

Or, if you need to only support some modern browsers:

```
var list = ...;

list.forEach(function (item) {
    string_to_url(item);
});
```

Comment: You're not putting the result or `string_to_url()` anywhere.

Comment: That's correct, the user didn't show what he wants to do with it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `string_to_url(list[i][0])`?

Answer (score 0):

This will update the list, replacing the strings in it with the translations.

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i][0] = string_to_url(list[i][0]);
}
```